# SSRS IF/Like/Then Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a SSRS report and in this report I have multiple types of accounts for our users. I obviously want to sum the total balance of certain accounts, but since there are multiple I am trying to specify the sum for each of these accounts. Like, AccountTypeA total is ### and AccountTypeB total is ###. I am building an expression but so far this is what I have:

```
IIF(Fields!AcctNum.Value Like "*.001"), True
```

I don't know what;s the "else" command when that field is true so it sums the balance I want for each type. Any help would be appreciated; I am new working with SSRS :). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get conditional `Sum` values (or any other aggregate) you can use an expression like:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!AcctNum.Value like "*.001", Fields!Balance.Value, Nothing))
```

This only considers rows that satisfy your first criterion (i.e. certain `AcctNum` values) for the aggregation.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Still getting used to these expressions, haha. Thanks a lot Ian, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use InStr.  E.g., =InStr(Fields!Description.Value, "car").

Evert occurance of the string Car will  increment by one so  (pesudo code)

if(InStr(Fields!Description.Value, "car") > 0, "True part","False Part")

Hope this helps.